# Integrate a quartic in a radical in the denominator of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x^{4}+6x^{2}-1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is a rather tough integration. I think it looks like an Elliptic Integral of some sort.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x^{4}+6x^{2}-1}}dx$$

Since there are no odd terms in the quartic, I thought maybe completing the square

would be OK. But I got nowhere. I even factored it into:

$3x^{4}+6x^2-1=((2\sqrt{3}-3)x^{2}+1)((2\sqrt{3}+3)x^{2}-1)$ and got nowhere.

I think the solution will involve the Gamma function in some manner.

Does anyone have a good starting point for this... like a clever substitution?.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? What kind of answer are you looking for? Numeric approximation? "Closed" form?

Comment: [$\int_1^\infty (3 x^4 + 6 x^2 - 1)^{-1/2} \mathrm{d}x \approx 0.47369$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1+%2F+Sqrt%5B3+x^4+%2B+6+x^2+-+1%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D)

Comment: Check out the page: http://everything2.com/title/elliptic+integral+standard+forms

Comment: Thank you all. I was looking for a closed form. I ran it through my Voyage 200 and got the .47369 as well. I was just wondering how it could be done by hand..if at all.  It ends up being a difficult Elliptic, then I will forget about it.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+1%2Fsqrt%283x%5E4%2B6x%5E2-1%29+from+1+to+infinity gives a result with two elliptic functions, $i$ and $\sinh^{-1}$.  It will also do the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As has been mentioned many times on this site, anytime you have an algebraic function containing the square root of a cubic or a quartic, you are bound to bump into an elliptic integral.

Usually, such things are handled by using Jacobian elliptic functions for substitutions (in a manner similar to using substitution with trigonometric or hyperbolic functions when you have the square root of a quadratic in an integral).

I'll skip the tedious details of figuring out the proper substitution, since [Byrd and Friedman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0) give a formula for handling your integral (formula 212.00 in their handbook):

$$\int_y^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{(t^2+a^2)(t^2-b^2)}}=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+y^2}}\right) \mid\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)$$

where $F(\phi|m)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Coming back to your integral, we let $u=2\sqrt{3}-3$ and $v=2\sqrt{3}+3$ such that

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{3x^4+6x^2-1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{uv}}\int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+1/u)(x^2-1/v)}}$$

Using the quoted formula, the integral reduces to

$$\frac1{\sqrt{u+v}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{v+uv}}\right)\mid\frac{v}{u+v}\right)$$

Substituting the values of $u$ and $v$ into this expression and simplifying, we have the result

$$\frac1{\sqrt[4]{48}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)\mid\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)$$

which agrees with the numerical result in the comments.

As an aside, I consider it a capital annoyance that *Mathematica* often returns results with complex amplitudes even for real results...

Comment: For those who want to puzzle out the needed substitution: $\mathrm{ns}^2(u|m)$ is involved in the required variable substitution.

Comment: M.: Welcome back! :)

Comment: Thanks @Mike; won't be staying very long, but I'm exploiting a gap in time I have.

Comment: Thanks, JM.  I agree about Mathematica. Maple, as well.